# Package install problems

Tags: r

Attempting to install packages from the office today, I'm getting:

```
>   install.packages("readr")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘readr’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
```

I have UNTICKED "Use secure download" (as you can see), and there is NO .Renviron or .Rprofiles that change the repos.

From the browser I am able to open `http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES` without any problem.

I've seen many posts like this, but none where the site is working ok in the browser. Is this likely to be a corporate firewall issue or something set incorrectly in my rstudio settings?

Comment: What version of R do you have installed?

Comment: @Phil  This is from R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) under RStudio 2022.02.2+485 "Prairie Trillium" Release (8acbd38b0d4ca3c86c570cf4112a8180c48cc6fb, 2022-04-19) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36